# PDFCreator COM-Interface save as PDF/A-1b

Tags: pdf, com

I'm creating an Application using the PDFCreator COM-Interface.

Is it possible to set PDF/A-1b as "AutosaveFormat" in PDFCreator.cCreator.cOptions?
Does anyone now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.
Just use **options.AutosaveFormat = 9** for PDF/A-1b.